# How to specify column type in pe:gcharts

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Simple question, but I can't come up with the answer.

In plain GCharts, I have this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value 2');
```

However, how can I specify that the values are *datetime* and *number* with the model builder of PrimerFaces?

The .addColumns() method just adds the items as `List<String>`:

```
GChartModelBuilder lineChartModelBuilder = new GChartModelBuilder();
lineChartModelBuilder.setChartType(GChartType.LINE);    
lineChartModelBuilder.addColumns("Time");
lineChartModelBuilder.addColumns("Value 1");
lineChartModelBuilder.addColumns("Value 2");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a very old PF Extensions version?  The reason I say that is back in 2016 this was fixed to use `List<Object>` instead of `List<String>` and was released in PrimeFaces Extensions 6.1 or higher.

Latest version of the code can be seen here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/gchart/model/GChartModelBuilder.java

Fixed back in 2016: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/commit/6c473bbc50920bfdaedca02b918c29a5ead8d4d0#diff-f3a907dcc2d19626bf60db5bbebba6be

**Update:**

If you want to add the data using key value pairs it should be possible.  Since GChart usese [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to turn the Java code into JSON to the client i would think if you put a String array value in the field it would deserialize like you were expecting.

Create a POJO representing the column:

```java
public class GChartModelColumn {

    // column label
    private final String label;

    // column type: number, date, datetime
    private final String type;

    public GChartModelColumn(String label, String type) {
        super();
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Then add the columns using the model above like...

```java
lineChartModelBuilder.addColumns(
new GChartModelColumn("Time", "datetime"), 
new GChartModelColumn("Value 1", "number"), 
new GChartModelColumn("Value 2", "number"));
```

Then in the JS code it converts your data object into a [Google DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable).

```
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.data);
```

Comment: Thank you Melloware. In the latest PF Extensions version I can add an Object as column, but how can I structure that object so the chart loads the alias and type? Something like .addColumns(new Pair("number", "Value 1")); or .addColumns(new Pair("datetime", "Time"));

Comment: It should work, but instead of adding the pair, it just creates two columns. If I insert 3 pairs, I get 6 columns: https://i.imgur.com/qtdiNYU.png

Comment: Yeah that's not right.  Looking at the source it just adds those objects: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/gchart/model/GChartModelBuilder.java#L56-L64 . So you might just have to look at how Google GSON deserializes to put the right objects in to get the key value pairs you want.  You are really close just need to fiddle with it to produce the JSON you want.

Comment: I get the following error: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Comment: OK I was able to test and get it working and updated my solution above!